# How to implement search box and ordering in DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to connect searchbox from DataTables.net with my data. I made mySQL database connected it via PHP and presented it on a page with support of AdminLTE and DataTables.net.

I used this tutorial as a learning material to do my project: https://codinginfinite.com/getting-started-web-application-php-mysql-tutorials/

Now I had successfully loaded  my data from SQL server into the html datatable but now I can't find the solution how to connect that data in the table to the search box(or order and paging function). Each time i try to search or sort my data I get a blank datatable as a result. Paging is not working as well and the table is always showed in full row count.

Can someone help, please?

1. This is my code for the php page where the table (in id="tablica") is sucesfully loaded. On the end of this code is ajax json script to get data from mySQL database.

```
    <?php
      $content = '<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Popis</h3>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-header -->
                  <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="tablica" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Naziv</th>
                        <th>Autori</th>
                        <th>Referenca</th>
                        <th>Datum u</th>
                        <th>Datum a</th>
                        <th>Pripada</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      </tbody>
                      
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
              </div>
            </div>';
      $header = '<h1> Popis <small>Ovdje se nalazi lista.</small> </h1>';
      include('../master.php');
    ?>
    
    <!-- page script -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../api/porodica/read.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var response="";
            for(var user in data){
                response += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].id_p+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].naziv_p+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].autor+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].ref+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].red_id+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].datum_u+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].datum_a+"</td>"+
                
                "<td><a href='update.php?id="+data[user].id_p+"'>Edit</a> | <a href='#' onClick=Remove('"+data[user].id_p+"')>Remove</a></td>"+
                "</tr>";
            }
            $(response).appendTo($("#tablica"));
        }
    });
  });

</script>
```

2. This is the end of my master.php file. I included all of the necessary css and js files for the DataTables to work.

```
     <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script src="../bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/app.min.js"></script>  
    <script>  
$(function () {  

$('#tablica').DataTable({  
"pageLength": 10,  
"paging": true,  
"lengthChange": false,  
"searching": true,  
"ordering": true,  
"info": false,
"autoWidth": false  
});  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Currently, DataTables thinks your table is empty. You need to let DataTables handle the JSON on your behalf. So, instead of building strings of HTML, and adding them to the DOM, you need to place your `ajax` call inside the DataTables configuration code, and let DataTables do all the work for you. Data added to the DOM is not directly visible to DataTables. See various examples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/). Once DataTables can see your data, it will be able to sort and filter it.

Comment: If you are still stuck after that, then edit your question, to show the structure of your JSON (and some sample data). That will help to provide more specific guidance.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem! Thanks for your hint and time! I did not change the approach of data insertion (DOM), but I rather forced ajax to run before the DataTables initialization and it still works like a charm!

Comment: Glad you solved it. That's a fair approach - you can certainly initalize DataTables for an HTML data that already has data in it. You may find this approach has limitations - depends on what you need to do with the table, and how its data gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution. The problem was the fact that ajax had an ansync nature. The ajax was reading the data into the table AFTER the DataTables initialized and DataTables thought that the table in question was empty all along.

I solved the problem after I introduced the DataTables initialization code after main ajax code with :complete (I moved it from masters.php into the page.php that have html table element and joined it in/after the ajax json script).

I am leaving the link where I found the solution:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50329/first-time-using-datatables-no-data-available-in-table

And the my code that is now working:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../api/porodica/read.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var response="";
            for(var user in data){
                response += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].id_p+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].naziv_p+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].autor+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].referenca+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].red_id+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].datum_u+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[user].datum_a+"</td>"+
                
                "<td><a href='update.php?id="+data[user].id_p+"'>Edit</a> | <a href='#' onClick=Remove('"+data[user].id_p+"')>Remove</a></td>"+
                "</tr>";
            }
            $(response).appendTo($("#tablica"));
        },
        
        complete: function () {

$("#tablica").DataTable({ 
"pageLength": 10,  
"paging": true,  
"lengthChange": false,  
"searching": true,  
"ordering": true,  
"info": false, 
"autoWidth": false  
});  
}


    });
  });
  
  
</script>
```